# Resolve a message code inside a JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a weird situation where I have to decode a Spring message code inside a JSP page.   Normally this would be handled by the Spring MVC `BindingResult` code as the response was passed back from the controller into the JSP, but this is not the normal situation.   The codes consist of an array of arbitrary strings like this, stored inside the [Spring `FieldError` object](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html):

```
myform.myobject.someCode.mylist[1].someCode
myform.myobject.someCode.someCode
myform.myobject.someCode.something
myform.myobject.someCode
```

and the message resolution process is handled by a Spring bean.  The [Message Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) we use is defined like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="messages,more_messages,even_more_messages,etcetera" />
</bean>
```

And I've included the bean into my JSP:

```
<jsp:useBean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" />
```

But I can't figure out how to make the call to `messageSource.getMessage(error,locale)` from inside the JSP.  I've tried this:

```
${messageSource.getMessage(fieldError,null)}
```

But that doesn't seem to work (also, I get a warning about nonstandard syntax.)   This is not something I've had to do before - I'm not sure how to reach into the `messageSource` bean and get the messages back.   Can anyone help me with the syntax, or with a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Spring already thought of this.   Their tag library, `spring.tld`, has a tag which already does this.    If you're familiar with the `spring-form.tld` library, the `spring.tld` library is a handy addition.   Documentation is here:   [Spring Framework Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring.tld)

I feel silly for not already knowing this, but sometimes you don't learn something until you need to.